# .Net, cobol, copybook

Tags: c#, .net, cobol

I have a project that is requiring extensive use of a data source that only exists as what appears to be a copy book.  For instance,

```
   01  CMT-COMM-MSTR-EXTRACT-RECORD.

       05 CMT-FIXED-AREA-1.

           10 CMT-COMMUNITY-RECORD-KEY.
               15 CMT-ALTERNATE-KEY.
                   20 CMT-ALTERNATE-KEY-STATE
                                       PIC  X(02).
                   20 CMT-ALTERNATE-KEY-COMM
                                       PIC  X(08).
               15 CMT-COMMUN-NBR.
```

The question is whether or not I have to write a crude parser for this stuff or if someone knows of some tools that will handle this nicely for me.  I am basically interested in either stuffing it in sql, oracle, or even just xml using .Net.  Seeing as I know nothing about this stuff, I just get worried I am going to handle something incorrectly.  Any input would be fantastic.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of tools out there for this purpose:

[COBOL copybook to XML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/)

[Another COBOL copybook to XML with some .NET specific notes:](http://www.dnzone.com/go?1068)